# Sending variable to controller from a view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am in this kind of situation

I have a controller where I am redirecting,as I need a certain code to proceed

```
 if(isset($code))
        {
            return back()->with('getCode', ' ');
```

And in my view, I am passing a form to get that value

```
@if(session('getCode')) 
  <form action="">
  <input type="text" name="confirmationcode"> 
  </form> 
@endif
```

Now in this controller, I want to access this confirmation code immediately

```
if(isset($code))
        {
            return back()->with('getCode', ' ');
            $code = request('confirmationcode');
            $business->book($code);
```

Since the logic `if(isset($code))` takes place after lots of coding, I don't want to go through start of the controller again.

Is there a way to access the `request('confirmationcode')` immediately from that view?

Comment: If it's taking you to a form why not just make them input the code that I can only guess has been stored within the database?

Comment: To store the code in the database I still have to redirect to a controller, this code is only a one time use so I think no use of storing it

Comment: It depends on what the purpose of the code is for. I have created something similar with an activation code that stores into the DB along with an activated field. If the code didnt match activated would stay 0 until it was correct and then would change to 1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can access the code before returning the function.

```
if(isset($code))
 {
    $code = request->input('confirmationcode');
    $business->book($code);

    return back()->with('getCode', ' ');
 }
```

Good page to read about requests. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests

Comment: I want to access the code after returning the function

Comment: When you return from the function, nothing is executed after the return statement. You should check this https://devzone.zend.com/6/php-101-php-for-the-absolute-beginner/